# AVPlayer Content Modes

Tags: swift, swift3, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a AVPlayer, and am using it as a background in my UIView as an aesthetic. To initialize and instantiate it, I do

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Background", ofType:"mp4") else {
        debugPrint("Background.mp4 not found")
        return
    }

    let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
    player.actionAtItemEnd = .none
    player.volume = 0.0

    //chage content mode ** TODO **

    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
    player.play()

}
```

When I run this, the video plays just as expected, however the AVPlayer sets the content mode to `fitToWidth` as a default. I searched through all the methods of `player` and `playerLayer` for some type of method on changing content type, but to no avail.

What I want is instead of `fitToWidth` I would like **`fitToHeight`**.

Any thoughts? Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of some really easy way to do this. When your video content is fetched, use *videoRect* method in AVPlayerLayer to extract the frame of the video image. Then resize your view according to the size of the image such that height goes to the extent that you want and width is proportion of the ratio of video height vs the height of view.